# SQLAlchemy Writing Nested Query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables:

```
table A

id | values
```

and

```
table B

id | foreign key to A | datestamp | val2
```

Given a list of `id`s for `A`, how do I get the joined result of `A` and `B` with only the rows from `B` that have the earliest `datestamp` for each matched `A`.

For example table B could have:

```
1 | 2 | 1/10/2015
1 | 2 | 1/2/2015
1 | 2 | 1/3/2015
```

I am only interested in the row

```
id_A | id_B | 1/2/2015 | values | val2
```

To my understanding in SQL, you can do something like

```
where timestamp = (select min(timestamp) from B.X where x.id = b.id)
```

However, how do I nest this select inside a SQLAlchemy query?

For example, I believe I can't just use

```
.filter(B.timestamp == (query(func.min(B.timestamp)).filter(A.id == B.foreign_key_to_A)))
```

Comment: [join](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) seems to be what you want instead of a nested query (it's not as resource intensive, either). More information on MySQL's JOIN statement [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Isn't this a combination of a nested query and a join?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you *can* just use:

```
B2 = aliased(B, name='b2')
s = session.query(func.min(B2.datestamp)).filter(B2.a_id == A.id)
q = (session
     .query(A.id, B.id, B.datestamp, A.values, B.val2)
     .join(B)
     .filter(B.datestamp == s)
     )
```